# GitHub for Windows installation error "Application cannot be started"

Tags: github, windows-xp

I get an error while trying to reinstall GitHub for Windows. I've tried downloading the installation file with Firefox and Chrome. I've also deleted the 2.0 folder in $USER\Local Settings\Apps. Here is the log.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1008
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1008 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_1_0_52_0/GitHub.exe.manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=1.0.52.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=1.0.52.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:30 PM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:31 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:31 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:32 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:33 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [7/24/2013 4:25:33 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [7/24/2013 4:28:57 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [7/24/2013 4:28:57 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [7/24/2013 4:28:57 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.GetRequestedRuntimeInfo(String pExe, String pwszVersion, String pConfigurationFile, UInt32 startupFlags, UInt32 runtimeInfoFlags, StringBuilder pDirectory, UInt32 dwDirectory, UInt32& dwDirectoryLength, StringBuilder pVersion, UInt32 cchBuffer, UInt32& dwLength)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Win32InterOp.SystemUtils.CheckSupportedImageAndCLRVersions(String path)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckApplicationPayload(CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 2):

you can delete the 2.0 folder : : %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apps (e.g. C:\users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps)

it works for me.
more details:https://superuser.com/questions/483515/github-for-windows-install-error

Comment: -1. Deleting the 2.0 folder will remove ALL apps deployed using ClickOnce, not just GitHub for Windows. It's like suggesting to delete Program Files because an app is not working...

Comment: I deleted the 2.0 folder....but in my case though I still cannot install github...whenever i try to install it the 2.0 folder is created again

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after an update. I went to uninstall the app from the control panel and from here you can revert to the previously working version.

Comment: any idea what happened with the update? It was the second time I got this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a couple years old, however posting it so that others can possibly use this and see if it helps.

So I recently had this issue and none of the suggested clean ups worked for me. I cleaned my clickonce cache, deleted 2.0 folder. Used IE as someone suggested instead of chrome and what not.

I finally found the issue. The access to C:/Windows/Temp/Deployment. Getting access to the Temp folder solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary memory cleaning solution doesn't work for me. I resolved my issue with this following steps:

1. It turns out that in Windows Task Manager's process tab a ClickOnce process dfsvc.exe is running. This process is starts when Visual Studio is opened as a VS instance. It need to start as GitHub Desktop instance.
2. The trick is that close all the Visual Studio and stop the dfsvc.exe process from Task Manager.
3. Then click GitHub for Desktop EXE and you will see a dfsvc.exe process. dfsvc.exe need to start as GitHub Desktop installation process and Wala! it installed perfectly.